# Prove $2^x≥x^2$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

I could not understand this proof. How are we able to divide both sides of the inequality with different things and claim that the inequality stays the same? Plus, is this an induction proof?

If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \ge 4$ then $2^x \ge x^2$ holds.

When $x = 4$ we have $2^4 = 16 \ge 16 = 4^2$.
We $x > 4$ we have $\frac{2^{x + 1}}{2^x} = 2$ and
$$
\frac{(x + 1)^2}{x^2}
= \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2
\le \left(\frac{5x}{4}\right)^2
$$
since $2 \le 1.5625$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes  , it is sort of an induction proof . We first show that the inequality holds for $x = 4$ . Now we find the ratios of the subsequent terms of $x^2$ and $2^x$ :

$$\dfrac{2^{x+1}}{2^x} = 2$$

And $$\dfrac{(x+1)^2}{x^2} = \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2$$

Note that for $x\ge 4$ , the expression$\color{#d05}{\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2 \le 2}$ . Since $2^x$ increases faster than $x^2$ , we can induct that $\color{#20f}{2^{x+1}\ge(x+1)^2}$for all $x\ge 4$ and the claim follows .

Comment: "Now we see that the next terms of the expressions ," what do you mean by this? Why and how are we able to do this?

Comment: @user734331 Consider the ratios of the terms of $2^x$ and $x^2$ . For $2^x$ , the next terms is **always $2$ times** that of previous term  , but for $x^2$ , it is $\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2$ , which is less than $2$ . Hence all subsequent terms of $x^2$ is always less than that of $2^x$

Answer (score 3):

The inductive hypothesis is the line $2^x\ge x^2$ for $x\ge4$. Essentially what these steps suggest is the following:$$(x+1)^2\le(1.25x)^2\le2x^2\le2\cdot2^x=2^{x+1}$$which completes the induction proof.

Comment: And note that $x + 1 \le 1.25 x$ only when $x \ge 4$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik It is already written.

Answer (score 2):

If $$2^x\ge x^2$$ is known to hold, then

$$2^{x+1}\ge(x+1)^2$$ because

$$2^{x+1}=2\cdot2^x\ge 2\cdot x^2\ge\left(\dfrac{x+1}{x}\right)^2x^2=(x+1)^2$$ provided $$\frac{x+1}x\le\sqrt2.$$